# get email language from Exchange WebService

Tags: c#

Is there a way to retrieve the sender language or region from an EmailMessage using WebServices.Data.ExchangeService from headers or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you can do it in several ways :

1. Some mail client include a tag like `lang='fr'` in email body
2. Region is specified in `EmailMessage.Culture` property
3. Header `Content-Language` may also contain the culture